# rbenv global version of ruby vs Sierra ruby version

Tags: macos, path, ruby

Following this OSX Sierra [tutorial](https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra) from the folks at gorails, I am having trouble getting rbenv global to associate the install of 2.3.0 with the `ruby` command and to override the default ruby version on my MacBook Air with macOS Sierra v10.12.2

```
$  rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.0
$  rbenv install 2.3.0
/Users/user_name/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0 installed
$  rbenv global 2.3.0
$  ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]
```

I tried `rbenv rehash` but ruby2.0.0 is still the default version. Briefly reviewing [this blog](http://technotes.iangreenleaf.com/posts/if-youre-having-ruby-environment-problems-i-feel-bad-for-you-son.html) about ruby and $PATH environment, I find I'm a little lost as to where the default Ruby "executable" actually lives...

gem env shows me that Ruby 2.0.0 lives here:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

and `whereis` tells me something different:

```
$  whereis ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

The tutorial says to add rbenv to my .bash_profile

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile`
```

Do I need to set my path to ignore the default ruby?

For what it is worth:

```
$  rbenv exec ruby -v
ruby 2.3.0p0 (2015-12-25 revision 53290) [x86_64-darwin16]
```

but obviously I don't want to write out the executive command everytime I want to use ruby... Per the blog, adding `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` doesn't make the `ruby` command defer to the rbenv global version... Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I entered this:

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile source ~/.bash_profile
```

but it should be:

```
echo 'if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi' >> ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bash_profile
```

...now it works fine.

Comment: @klanomath ::tips hat, nods::